# Error in writing to files (python)

Tags: python, file, ssh, io, terminal

In a particular program while I am using ssh, I have to write/append the output that appears in the command line to a file 
I use this to do so using the syntax >> output_file

While the program is running, i see that the outputs are written to this file

But some outputs go missing and also, suddenly a bunch of the outputs get replaced by \00\00\00\00\00\00\00\

I am viewing the file using gedit. It diplays this error:
"There was a problem opening the file /export/validation_files/matrix_result_shared.txt.The file you opened has some invalid characters. If you continue editing this file you could corrupt this document.
You can also choose another character encoding and try again."
Character Encoding "Current Locale (UTF-8)

The code:

```
    ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())    
    ssh.connect(ips_in_file[0]) 
    cmd="/usr/local/mpich2/bin//mpiexec --wdir /export/validation_files/ -f /export /validation_files/freeVMs_shared.txt -n "+str(numVMs)+" python mulpar_new.py "+ s +" >> /export/validation_files/matrix_result_shared.txt"
    ssh.exec_command(cmd)
```

The output is of the form "float_value1 float_value2". The file should consist of a series of these float values each in a different line.

Example : 
11.9450 1407143946.2747 
17.1227 1407143960.3452 
11.5677 1407143980.0876 
10.9824 1407143994.7366 
\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\0022.4466 1407144010.2266

Comment: How abaout posting the code?

Comment: Can you tell what kind of output is missing? And what kind of output is recorded into output_file?

Comment: For simplicity, you can display the file with the `cat` command: `cat myfile`

Comment: The results are getting replaced. cat didn't work.